# Highcharts plot markers move behind spline graph animation

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts, spline

I've just wrote a simple graph. In this graph, the lines moves before the markers therefore, it seems very strange to me. I'm pretty sure this is about animation properties but I couln't find what causes problem.

You can inspect my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/md7hW/3/)

I set values with the following code

```
function () {

    // set up the updating of the chart each second
    var series1 = this.series[0];
    var series2 = this.series[1];
    var series3 = this.series[2];

    setInterval(function () {
        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
            y = Math.random();
        series1.addPoint([x, y], true, true);

        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
            y = Math.random();
        series2.addPoint([x, y], true, true);

        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
            y = Math.random();
        series3.addPoint([x, y], true, true);

    }, 1000);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by addPoint and redraw all chart 3 times. So I advice not redrawing chart for 1/2 points, only for last.

http://jsfiddle.net/md7hW/4/

```
setInterval(function() {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                    y = Math.random();
                            series1.addPoint([x, y], false, true);

                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                    y = Math.random();
                            series2.addPoint([x, y], false, true);

                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                    y = Math.random();
                            series3.addPoint([x, y], true, true);

                        }, 1000);
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint()

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I totally forgot to change that.

Answer (score 0):

@sebastian, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I was facing a similar issue, but dealing with dynamic data.  I found that passing false for the redraw parameter when adding my points, then evoking redraw on the chart object to work best for my case.

```
var chart, REFRESH_DELAY = 1000;
function requestData(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/reports/realtime",
        format:"json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length && i < chart.series.length; i++) {
                var series = chart.series[i], 
                    shift = series.data.length > 20,
                    point = data[i];
                series.addPoint(point, false, shift);
            }
            chart.redraw();
            setTimeout(requestData, REFRESH_DELAY);
        }
    });
}
```